# SVG Transformation - Flip Horizontally

Tags: html, css, web, svg, css-transforms

I need to flip this SVG horizontally - can't find anything online. Here it is:

```html
  <svg id="bigHalfCircle" style="display: block;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <path d="M 0,100 C 40,0 60,0 100,100 Z"/>
        </svg>
```

Any help appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can just set a transform to flip things and then move the shape (as it's flipped about the origin).

```html
<svg id="bigHalfCircle" style="display: block;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path transform="scale(1, -1) translate(0, -100)" d="M 0,100 C 40,0 60,0 100,100 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: missing % in translate(0, -100%)

Comment: @manuel-84 incorrect you can only use units with CSS transforms

Comment: This flips vertical, not horizontal

Comment: yes, its a vertical flip, same idea but the scale negative value needs to be the first (x axis) param like scale(-1, 1).  it doesn't rotate around the centre either so the translate portion just shifts it back on to the canvas, you may need to adjust this number based on the size you're working with.

Answer (score 51):

If you can use CSS (this does not work when imported into Inkscape as of today), you can also use a CSS scale transform, which has the advantage that it is based on the element's center by default: `transform: scale(-1,1);`

```html
<svg id="bigHalfCircle" style="display: block; transform: scale(-1,1)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d="M 0,100 C 40,0 60,0 100,100 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you, this worked great to flip an svg declared inline in a css stylesheet via `url("data:image/svg+xml`

Answer (score 1):

Another more simpler approach may be to use `transform: rotate(180deg)` wherever you want to flip an element.

Comment: that is flip for x plus y but if you only want to flip x or y this wont help